# Error using System.out.printf

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am getting this error: "this method must return a result of type string" for this code. Also, I haven't been able to find much about the .printf method (I just got it from my textbook since I needed to format this exactly like they had in there). Was this method removed?

```
public String toString()
{
    System.out.println("Shown are the prices for " +
            "each seat. A 0 indicates the seat is " +
            "unavailable.");
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%8d", seatArray[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the error says it all. Return String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String toString() // returns a String
```

The `return` type of this method is a `String`, but you don't have a return statement at all. You need to have a return statement, which returns a String from this method. There is no problem with using a `System.out.printf`.

```
public String toString()
{
    System.out.println("Shown are the prices for " +
            "each seat. A 0 indicates the seat is " +
            "unavailable.");
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%8d", seatArray[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return someString; // return statement is required as the method return type is String and not void
}
```

Note that, you can't change the return type to `void`, because when you use the `toString()` name for your method, it is overriding the `toString()` method of the `Object` class, whose return type is `String`. You can either rename the method and make it `void`, or if you wish to keep the same name(and override the `Object.toString()`), then you need to have a return statement for sure.

```
public void printArray() // Something like this
```

And yeah, whether the return type is `void` or `String`, you can always print your array in the fashion you've done. Just that if its a `String` return type, you'll have to return a `String` along with the printing you did in the method.

Comment: Thank you again, RJ. So is there a way to still print it like that from this method? I switched it to public void, but then it gave this error "The return type is incompatible with Object.toString()"

Comment: @user1953907 If you are using a void method, don't name it `toString()`, name it something like `print()` or `display()`.

Comment: @user1953907 - I edited my answer to answer to your doubt. Let me know if you need more clarity on it! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a String as per your method signature. Try this.

```
public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()'
    sb.append("Shown are the prices for " +
           "each seat. A 0 indicates the seat is " +
           "unavailable.\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            sb.append(String.format("%8d\n", seatArray[i][j]));
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, [`PrintStream.printf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) was not removed. `System.out` is an instance of `java.io.PrintStream`.